# Which method should I use to find gradient direction of pixels in an image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, pattern-recognition

I came across two methods of finding gradient magnitudes and direction

1:

```
I=imread('12.jpg');
I1=rgb2gray(I);
ed=edge(I1,'canny',0.4);
[gx gy]=gradient(double(ed),0.5);
figure;
imshow(I);
gm=sqrt(gx.^2+gy.^2);
gdp=atan2(gy,gx);
figure;
imshow(gm);
figure; imshow(gdp);
```

gm will store gradient magnitude and gdir the direction

2: An inbuilt matlab function

```
[gm gdp]=imgradient(ed);
```

Both the outputs are entirely different. Which one should I use for implementation of Stroke Width Transform?

Comment: I do not use Matlab so I may be wrong but: the canny filter screw your gradients so the result is direction and magnitude of edges not image itself you can derive the image by x,y instead (I am guessing that is the `gradient` for so just try to remove the canny filter). the `sqrt` and `atan2` part stays as is. No clue what is the result of `imgradient` Also you should post input image and the 2 outputs

Answer (score 1):

Although the original paper doesn't state which method should be used, I found that in two popular implementations of SWT: [DetectText](https://github.com/tleyden/DetectText) and [CCV](https://github.com/liuliu/ccv) Sobel operator is utilized.

You are getting different outputs because you computed gradient on Canny's method output (not Sobel on input image, as it should be done). Also `imgradient` returns gradient orientation in degrees, `atan2` result is in radians. You should use `imgradient` to get magnitude and orientation or `imgradientxy` to get the directional gradients if you want compute orientation yourself.

For clues, you could refer to this [file](https://github.com/aperrau/DetectText/blob/master/TextDetection.cpp) or their [technical report](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4670/2010fa/projects/final/results/group_of_arp86_sk2357/Writeup.pdf).